# What does *.* stand for in "Local Address" of a netstat result?

Tags: networking, openbsd, bsd

when I do the following `netstat` :

```
$ netstat -nap udp -f inet
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto   Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
udp          0      0  192.168.1.23.37177     212.83.160.142.123
udp          0      0  192.168.1.23.44025     195.154.189.15.123
udp          0      0  192.168.1.23.48639     163.172.228.190.123
udp          0      0  192.168.1.23.26792     5.135.3.88.123
udp          0      0  *.514                  *.*
udp          0      0  *.*                    *.*
```

I see the first four udp lines are for NTP : OK

The next line (port 514) is for syslogd : OK

But what does the next line mean ?

```
udp          0      0  *.*                    *.*
```

Anyone can connect to any port from anywhere ? Or what is the process that listen to any port on my machine ? how can I find that process ?

**EDIT**

```
$ fstat | grep udp
_ntp     ntpd       35059    6* internet dgram udp 192.168.1.23:5862 <-> 212.83.158.83:123
_ntp     ntpd       35059    7* internet dgram udp 192.168.1.23:45616 <-> 51.255.141.154:123
_ntp     ntpd       35059    8* internet dgram udp 192.168.1.23:23331 <-> 5.135.3.88:123
_ntp     ntpd       35059    9* internet dgram udp 192.168.1.23:18127 <-> 129.250.35.251:123
_syslogd syslogd    58451    4* internet dgram udp *:514
_syslogd syslogd    58451    5* internet6 dgram udp *:514
_dhcp    dhclient   57064    3* internet dgram udp *:0
root     dhclient   42561    3* internet dgram udp *:0
```

Is it dhclient that creates that line in netstat ? How can a process (it's not a daemon) be bound to *:0 ?

More info :

```
$ ps aux | grep -i dhclient
root     42561  0.0  0.0   616   484 ??  Is    10:39PM    0:00.01 dhclient: em0 [priv] (dhclient)
_dhcp    57064  0.0  0.0   744   516 ??  Isp   10:39PM    0:00.00 dhclient: em0 (dhclient)
```

**EDIT 2:**
In dhclient(8), I read :

> dhclient monitors the system for changes to the default route and
>   re-checks whether it should write its resolv.conf when possible
>   changes are detected.

Could it be that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an unspecified or wildcard port (or address); from [`netstat(1)`](http://man.openbsd.org/netstat)

> Unspecified or “wildcard” addresses and ports appear as a single ‘*’

So `*.514` is syslog per `/etc/services` listening for connections from anywhere (see [`listen(2)`](http://man.openbsd.org/listen) for details on this) and `*.*` is something listening for any port on any address the system might have. The foreign addresses are `*.*` for these as nothing is connected, unlike the NTP related connections on port 123 which do.

Per the `fstat | grep udp` command by @Kusalananda the listeners are for `dhclient`; listening on port 0 is actually possible on some systems (IRIX I recall having a TCP/0 listener) though in this case the `dhclient` code is making a slightly unusual socket call so `ioctl` can be performed related to interfaces, see the `get_ifname` subroutine in `dhclient.c` under the `src/sbin` source tree for a portion of that code.

Comment: Yes, but what is listening to any port from any source ? it's frightening. I don't have inetd running. How can I see the process that creates that line in netstat ?

Comment: @JérômeRadix `fstat | grep udp`

Comment: @Kusalananda I see that dhclient is listening to *:0 but that's even strangier because 0 cannot be bound to a daemon I think. I've added the results of fstat in my question.

Comment: @JérômeRadix `dhclient` isn't currently listening. It's only listening when communicating with a DHCP server.  The 0 port for a client means "any available port".

Comment: @JérômeRadix A "daemon" is an ordinary program. There's nothing magical about daemons. They're just not utilities a user would be expected to run. That's all.

Comment: In dhclient(8), I read : "dhclient monitors the system for changes to the default route and re-checks whether it should write its resolv.conf when possible changes are detected." Could it be that feature that creates that line in netstat ?